# gst multifilesink of datestamped files every 5 minutes

Tags: bash, gstreamer, raspberry-pi3

I've searched and found some relevant threads but I'm just a bit too new to bash to comprehend so I figured I post my explicit problem. I've got a raspberry pi with a camera taking a picture every 5 minutes. It names the file $DATE.jpg where DATE=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y_%H%M"). So at 1:35PM the filename would be 07-28-2018_1335.jpg. After each day I'm wanting to make a gst script to combine them all for the day into an avi and then flush out the directory. So far I have:

```
DATE=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
TAIL=%04d
NAME=$(echo ${DATE}_${TAIL})
gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location=/home/pi/usbdrive/archive/$NAME.jpg index=0 caps="image/jpeg,framerate=5/1" ! jpegdec ! omxh264enc ! avimux ! filesink location=/home/pi/usbdrive/video-archive/$DATE.avi
```

If I have it set to take a picture every minute, it seems to work for 60 frames as last 2 digits resets to 00 on a new hour. Can't figure out how to tell it to take every file based on every 5 digits while also resetting after 55 or every digit while resetting at 59. Any help help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: this question has been ashed on ubnix+linux where it is actually on-topic

Answer (score 0):

`multifilesrc` is to read file sequences. Your sequence is way to complex. A sequence is expected not to have any gaps and increases by 1. Create files with real sequences as names instead of hour and minutes.